# Flutter code screen widgets colour problem/query

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm a complete beginner doing an old online flutter course.

Why is my code not highlighted in yellow eg. 'MaterialApp or Scaffold' like the instructors[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Aet.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nez7t.jpg) Additionally, when I'm inserting a widget, it does not type ahead to give me the option.

Thanks

I'm up to date on all Android studio update,

Comment: My assumption is that you haven't set up Dart linter. I used VS Code and not Android Studio though, so I can't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed flutter sdk? You have to provide more detail. Kindly check your sdk. if your sdk is good then run **flutter delete** command and then **flutter pub get** in your terminal.